# Comparar Fechas de entre 2 tablas y asignar un valor en una consulta Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo problemas al hacer una consulta, y es que es mi primer caso con este tipo de requerimientos y no se me ocurre una buena idea para hacerlo. Para no poner el código que tengo que son mas 38 lineas voy a recrear mi consulta con tablas.

Tengo 2 tablas de la siguiente manera:

```
**Tabla 1: Semana**
Id    semana     fecha_ini             fecha_fin
1     semana 1   2018-12-28 00:00:00   2019-01-03 23:59:00
2     semana 2   2019-01-04 00:00:00   2019-01-10 23:59:00
3     semana 3   2019-01-11 00:00:00   2019-01-17 23:59:00

**Tabla 2: Ventas**
Id    usuario    fecha_venta           producto
1     jramirez   2018-12-29 15:12:25   Cepillo
1     rmartinez  2019-01-06 10:25:40   Pasta Dental
1     speña      2019-01-12 08:01:10   Jabon
```

**Resultado que necesito**

Necesito comparar la **fecha_venta** y validar en que rango se encuentra según 
fecha_ini y fecha_fin de la tabla **semana**, generando como resultado una 
columna **Semana** con el valor correspondiente:

```
Id    usuario    fecha_venta           Semana
1     jramirez   2018-12-29 15:12:25   semana 1
1     rmartinez  2019-01-06 10:25:40   semana 2
1     speña      2019-01-12 08:01:10   semana 3
```

Por favor, su ayuda, se los agradezco mucho. Saludos.

Comment: ¿las fechas no chocaras unas entre otras? Es decir, ¿los rangos no invadirán el rango de otra semana?

Comment: Hola que tal, los intervalos son definidos y no se cruzan. He realizado intervalos hasta el 2020 pero he puesto solo 3 de ejemplo.

Comment: Vale, entonces [**aquí tienes mi respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299126/comparar-fechas-de-entre-2-tablas-y-asignar-un-valor-en-una-consulta-mysql-workb/299131#299131)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando un `inner join` con la tabla semana y utiliza la condición `BETWEEN` para el rango de fecha.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT Ventas.Id,Ventas.usuario,Ventas.fecha_venta,Semana.semana FROM Ventas
INNER JOIN Semana ON Ventas.fecha_venta BETWEEN Semana.fecha_ini AND Semana.fecha_fin
```

otra opción

```
SELECT Ventas.Id,Ventas.usuario,Ventas.fecha_venta,Semana.semana FROM Ventas
INNER JOIN Semana ON Ventas.fecha_venta >= Semana.fecha_ini AND Ventas.fecha_venta<=Semana.fecha_fin
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias por tu respuesta. Ahora ampliaste mis recursos en conocimientos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes encontrar la solución de tu problema haciendo un **SELECT** dentro del **SELECT** que tenga un **WHERE BETWEEN** adentro.

Como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
v.usuario,
v.fecha_venta,
(
  SELECT 
    s.semana
  FROM semana AS s
  WHERE v.fecha_venta BETWEEN s.fecha_ini AND s.fecha_fin 
) AS semana
FROM ventas AS v;
```

Puedes verlo en [**este fiddler adjunto que te hice**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fzXCgbYM3VtBpPvN5LGt3V/0).

Comment: Es increíble lo que has hecho, no sabia que se podía hacer de esta forma. Muchas Gracias, eres un capo.